# Time complexity of Boolean operators on pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-complexity

I'm writing a short program for some standard dataframe operations on Pandas but the time complexity of the program is O(n) due to the following piece of code:

```
criteria = ((cars["Color"] == order["CarColors"]["Include"]) \
    & (cars["Size"] != order["CarSize"]["Exclude"])

cars[criteria]
```

criteria is used to filter the cars dataframe as I only want to include certain colors and exclude certain sizes. I ran the program for an increasingly large cars file and the time complexity increases linearly with the number of points.

[image]

I also tried np.isin as below but it actually made the performance worse. Anyone have an idea how I can improve the time complexity? I thought Boolean operators would be quicker than this.

```
criteria = np.isin(cars["Color"],order["CarColors"]["Include"]) \
    & np.isin(cars["Size"],order["CarSize"]["Exclude"], invert=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that line of code is O(n^2)?

Comment: @user3483203 When I ran the program for an increasingly large number of data, the graph of the number of data points versus the time to complete the program (data points on log scale) gave what looks to be a 2nd order polynomial. 

Isn't that how one determines time complexity?

Comment: @user3483203 Chris, I've added the graph of the complexity. Does it look correct to you? There are other lines of code in the program but I'm pretty sure this line is the one slowing things down. Thanks.

Comment: How did you achieve the plot? I bet there is more to it than simple condition.

Comment: @harvpan Sorry, the plot should read "number of rows". Each time I repeat the program run, I increase the number of rows in cars by an order of magnitude. Each row contains 4 columns with the first folding numerical data and the remaining three have text. Is my method of computing time complexity incorrect?

Comment: I don't understand the comparisons you are making. Could you provide some sample data? How do you expect, in your first snippet, the values to be compared? how shall pandas know what to do? Is order a Dataframe or a different object?

Comment: How can this be any better than O(n) ? It needs to look at every row. This isn't O(n^2)... if that is the question?

Comment: @AndyHayden yes, it's not O(n^2). That was my mistake, I was misreading the crude time complexity plot that I made. I have attached the new plot - it looks to be O(n). So, this can't be any better than O(n)?

Comment: @brownbread not this line... but it's hard to say without the rest of the code. Are you doing this M times? Maybe this could be better as a groupby etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try and evaluate it like this:

```
car_color = order["CarColors"]["Include"]
car_size = order["CarSize"]["Exclude"]
cars.query("Color == @car_color and Size != @car_size")
```

When you do boolean indexing, you create some temporary arrays. If these arrays are much bigger than your CPU cache memory, then the query method could enhance performance a bit. [source](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html)